# SQL WHERE Clause with OR

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I'm trying to add a record "name2" to this line of code, so the page will display articles for name1 or name2 users.
This is the current code, which only displays articles for name1 users.

```
$table = ARTICLE;
if (isContributor()) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name1=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

This code works and displays articles for name2 users:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name2=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

And when I want to display the articles for both users, I use the following code, but it breaks the page:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name1 OR name2=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Can you provide me with the correct line of code?

Comment: @Dharman: `.$_SESSION['user_id']`  is a system supplied value, there's no input.

Comment: @dnoeth It doesn't matter where the value comes from. Input is input and it should all be parameterized. There is really no excuse to do it with SQL injection.

Answer (score 3):

This ORed condition can be rewritten using IN, probably

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ".$_SESSION['user_id']" IN (name1,name2)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name1 OR name2=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE name1=".$_SESSION['user_id']." OR name2=".$_SESSION['user_id'];
```